# How to construct a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ such that $A^3=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Construct a $2$ $\times$ $2$ matrix $A$ ($\neq$ $I$) with entries from $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A^3=I$.

First give me some hint. How to construct this kinds of matrices, is there any rule...

Comment: If I say "I have a transformation $T$ such that, if I do it three times, I go back to the way things were," what would you conjure up?

Comment: think rotations

Answer (score 1):

Hint: rotation matrices.  Particularly, the rotation by $120˚$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the eigenvalues of $A$ must satisfy $\lambda^3=1$ and if complex, must be complex
conjugates.

One possibility: Eigenvalues are  both $1$. This is not possible since $A$ is not the identity matrix and Jordon block of size 2 will not work.

The other possibility is $\lambda = -1/2 \pm i \sqrt{3}/2$. This gives
$$A = \pmatrix{-{{1}\over{2}}&{{\sqrt{3}}\over{2}}\cr -{{\sqrt{3}}\over{2
 }}&-{{1}\over{2}}\cr }$$